# Large file upload with resume

Tags: http, web-applications, file-upload, ftp, applet

I have a file manager app that lets users upload their file, but in some situations they need to upload large files and they don't have access to a ftp client, I was wondering if there's a ready made tool that allowed them to upload files via ftp from the browser, or any other method that supported resuming.

It should also work on ios/android devices. Pre-made configurable free applets might work if you know of one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a resume-supported solution, but you can check Flash-based uploaded. I prefer swf-upload.

Flash upload will work on Android. iPhone browser (as I know) don't allow uploads.